# Find the amount of atoms for a given mass

Tags: stoichiometry, atoms, mole

The atomic mass of two elements A and B is 40 and 80 respectively. If x g of A contains y atoms, how many atoms are present in 2x g of B?

I have tried to solve by assuming that

- x g of A has y atoms
- so x g of B has 2y atoms, because atomic weight of B is 2 times higher than A
- so 2x g of B contains 4 y atoms.

But the answer key says it was wrong, the correct answer is y. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: >The atomic mass of two elements A and B is 40 and 80 respectively. If x g of A contains y atoms, how many atoms are present in 2x g of B? Since B has a mass double that of A, 2X g og B should have the same amount of atoms as 1 X g og A. The answer is y atoms.

Answer (score 4):

For the elements *A* and *B*, the relation between the number of atoms **n**, the mass **m**, and the atomic mass **M** is given by

> $$n_A = \frac{m_A}{M_A}\quad,\quad n_B = \frac{m_B}{M_B}$$

Your assignment states:
$$m_B = 2\cdot m_A $$
$$M_B = 2\cdot M_A $$

Solve for $n_B$ ;-)

---

*I seriously suggest to practise these calculations a lot. Ask your tutor for more worksheets or find a workbook (with solutions). Solve it alone, or work in groups. No matter how, you have to practise.*

*If you are in doubt, where to divide and where to multiply, remember:*

**Units are your friends!**